# for loop with if statement - array without comma

Tags: php, arrays

This is my part of code:

```
for( $i = $aKeys['iStart']; $i < $aKeys['iEnd']; $i++ )
{
        $aData = $this->aProducts[$aProducts[$i]];

        $content .= '"'.$aData['sName'].'"';

        if ($i < $aKeys['iEnd'])  
        {
           $content .= ', '; 
        } 
        $i2++;
}
```

Full code gives me this as result:

```
["word1", "word2", "word3", ]
```

This is a simple array, which I will use, but this won't work because after word3 there is a comma sign. How to write this if statement to get result like: `["word1", "word2", "word3"]` ?

Comment: you can use `array_push();` to eliminate the comma thingy :)

Comment: instead of appending to $content you can create array like $content = [] and use array_push($aData['sName'] and to get result like ["word1","word2","word3"] simply use json_encode($content);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a condition on the length-1 to fix your bug.

```
for( $i = $aKeys['iStart']; $i < $aKeys['iEnd']; $i++ ){
        $aData = $this->aProducts[$aProducts[$i]];

        $content .= '"'.$aData['sName'].'"';

        if ($i < $aKeys['iEnd']-1) {
        $content .= ', '; 
        } 
        $i2++;
      }
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use rtrim() to remove comma.

```
rtrim($content, ',');
```

As I can see you want all names as comma separated. Than you can do like that as well :

```
$content = array();
for( $i = $aKeys['iStart']; $i < $aKeys['iEnd']; $i++ ){
    $aData = $this->aProducts[$aProducts[$i]];
    $content[] = $aData['sName'];
}

echo implode(',',$content);
```

Comment: please add more detail and maybe a link to the actual function page : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

Comment: Oops sorry we need to use rtrim. Thanks @Sougata

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use an `array` for this. And at the end simply `implode` them.

```
for( $i = $aKeys['iStart']; $i < $aKeys['iEnd']; $i++ ){
    $aData = $this->aProducts[$aProducts[$i]];
    $content[] = '"'.$aData['sName'].'"';
}

$content = '"' . implode('","', $content) . '"';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( $i = $aKeys['iStart']; $i < $aKeys['iEnd']; $i++ ){
        $aData = $this->aProducts[$aProducts[$i]];

        $content .= '"'.$aData['sName'].'"';

        if ($i < $aKeys['iEnd'] && $i!=($aKeys['iEnd']-1)) { //this condition also considers $i not to be the last element of the array before appending the comma to it.
        $content .= ', '; 
        } 
        $i2++;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_push();` function

```
$var = array();

loop(condition){
    array_push($var, $value);
}
```

Comment: OP wants a string with `,` separated values not an array.

Comment: @Sougata You should use Matt's solution and to get comma separated result you can use json_encode($array)

Comment: @akshaykhale, Yes maybe but OP wants manual `,` separation. It's okay ^_^